# Can I charge a 4S2P lithium battery pack with a 20V laptop power adapter?

Tags: battery-charging

I plan to build a 4S2P battery pack and have chosen to use a 30A BMS. My understanding is that the BMS will stop the individual cells from charging beyond 4.2V.

In such an environment, can I charge my battery pack using my 20V 4.5A laptop power adapter, or do I specifically need a 16.8V 1-2A charger?

The measured capacity of the cells are 1500 mAh or 3AH in the finished battery pack.

**EDIT:**

This is the BMS and charger I bought, respectively:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/192051343486

http://www.ebay.com/itm/332048841686

I am going to use two 4x18650 battery holders. I will connect the cells to the BMS as mentioned in the diagram and will connect the P+/P- to a 5.5x2.1mm female power jack.

I can then plug in my charger into that or plug in my motor or other electronics into that. Does this sound good?

Comment: Your BMS should have some kind of datasheet or manual with current and voltage ratings.

Comment: The ad says it's a protection board, not a charging circuit. You'll need a proper charger for that type of battery - or keep the Fire Brigade on speed dial.

Comment: No. You need a charger to charge your battery pack. You cannot charge lithium ion battery packs with fixed voltage supplies. You need CC/CV, and you need to detect end of charge, at which point the charging must cease.

Comment: @mkeith and BrianDrummond Can you see the updated question and post as solution.

Comment: You still need a charger. There are no detailed specifications listed for that power supply. It may or may not be a real charger. For example, does it have any method of detecting end of charge? Or does it float at 16.8V forever? How accurate is the 16.8V? I might suggest you go in a different direction. Instead of building a permanent pack, and charging as a pack, maybe you can use individual 18650 cells, and charge them with an off-the-shelf charger (for example, chargers made by NiteCore).